# the problem: the code below work flawlessly in dev but after uploaded to Heroku it's working sometimes,

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io

I am trying to get socket.io to work with Heroku but it doesn't play well.
the problem: the code below work flawlessly in dev but after uploaded to Heroku it's working sometimes,

1.don't see anything weird on logs.

2.the data saved to DB and will appear after refresh

3.refresh helps to sockets sometimes.

4.there is no pattern to it, sometime it will work ok for an hour and some time won't last a minute

5.heroku features:enable http-session-affinity also done

server:

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Rooms = mongoose.model("Rooms");
const Chat = mongoose.model("Chats");

const jwt = require("jwt-then");

const socketChat = (app, io) => {

  io.use(async (socket, next) => {
    try {
      const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
      const payload = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
      socket.userId = payload.id;
      socket.id = payload.id;
      socket.name = payload.username;
      console.log({ socketisd: socket.userId, name: socket.name });
      next();
    } catch (err) { }
  });

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("Connected: " + socket.name);

    socket.on("disconnect", () => {
      console.log("Disconnected: " + socket.name);
    });

    socket.on("joinRoom", async ({ roomId },callback) => {
      socket.join(roomId);
      console.log(` ${socket.name} joined room: ` + roomId);
      socket.to(roomId).emit("live", { name: socket.name, live: true, roomId });
      callback({
        status: "ok"
      });
    });

    socket.on("leaveRoom", async ({ roomId },callback) => {
      socket.leave(roomId);
      console.log(` ${socket.name} left room: ` + roomId);
      socket.to(roomId).emit("live", { name: socket.name, live: false, roomId });
      callback({
        status: "ok"
      });
    });
    socket.on("typing", async ({ msg, roomId }) => {
      let name = "";
      if (msg.text && msg.text.trim().length > 0) {
        let length = msg.text.length;
        name = length > 0 ? socket.name : "";
      }
      socket.to(roomId).emit("typingclient", { name });
    });
    socket.on(
      "chatroomMessage",
      async ({ roomId, message, name, profileImg, timestamp, type, date }) => {

        if (message.trim().length > 0) {
          io.to(roomId).emit("newMessage", {
            roomId,
            user: socket.userId,
            message,
            name,
            type,
            date,
            profileImg,
            timestamp,
            recived: true,
          });
          let room = await Rooms.findById(roomId).populate("messages");

          if (type === "reject") {
            await Chat.findOneAndUpdate(
              { roomId, type: "dateConfirm" },
              { type: "reject", message },
              { new: true }
            );
          }

          else {
            const newMessage = new Chat({
              roomId,
              date,
              type,
              user: socket.userId,
              message,
              name,
              profileImg,
              timestamp,
              recived: true,
            });
            await newMessage.save();
            room.messages.push(newMessage);
            await room.save();
          }

          let theOtherGuy =await room.users.find((user) => user != socket.userId);
          io.to(theOtherGuy).emit("room", room);
        }
      }
    );
  });
};

module.exports = socketChat;
```

client:

```
      /**
   * Sends message with emit socket to server
   * @param {Object} event Default Browser Event Object
   * @param {String} text content of message
   * @param {String} date Date for schedualing
   * @param {String} type type of the message (reject,request etc...)
   */
  const sendMessage = (event, text, date = null, type = null) => {
    event && event.preventDefault();
    if (socket) {
      socket.emit("chatroomMessage", {
        roomId,
        date,
        type,
        name: currentUser.user.username,
        profileImg: currentUser.user.profileImageUrl,
        timestamp: new Date(),
        recived: false,
        message: text,
      });
      setText("");
    
    socket.emit("typing", {
      msg: "",
      roomId,
    });
  }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
   
    if (socket) {
      socket.emit("joinRoom", {roomId},(answer)=>
      console.log("joinRoom",roomId,answer)
      );
      socket.on("newMessage", (message) => {
        console.log({message})
        if (message.type === "reject")
          setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages.filter(m => m.type !== 'dateConfirm'), message]);
        else
          setMessages((prevMessages) => [...prevMessages, message]);
      });

      socket.on("live", (message) => {
        console.log(message)
        message.live ? setSucess(`user ${message.name} has connected`) : setErr(`user ${message.name} has left`)
      });
      socket.on("typingclient", (name) => {
        setTyping(name);
      });
    }
    return () => {
      if (socket) {
        socket.emit("leaveRoom", {roomId},(answer)=>
        console.log("leaveRoom",roomId,answer)
        );
      }
      //Component Unmount
    };
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [socket]);
```

and main where i define my socket:

```
  const [socket, setSocket] = React.useState(null);

  const setupSocket = () => {
    console.log("socket4")

    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("jwtToken");
    if (token && !socket) {
      const newSocket = io("/", {
        query: {
          token: sessionStorage.getItem("jwtToken"),
        },
        path: '/socket'
      });

      newSocket.on("disconnect", () => {
        // setSocket(null);
        // makeToast("error", "Socket Disconnected!");
      });

      newSocket.on("connect", () => {
        // makeToast("success", "Socket Connected!");
        console.log("Socket Connected");
      });

      setSocket(newSocket);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser && !socket) setupSocket();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [currentUser, socket]);
```

ststic.json:

```
{
    "root":"build/",
    "routes":{
        "/**":"index.html"
    },
    "proxies":{ 
        "/api/":{"origin":"${API_URL}"},
        "/socket/":{"origin":"${SOCKET_URL}"}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the Io object did not like

```
       socket.id = payload.id;
```

I have removed it and everything is working now.
I think it may have resulted from different keys in the Io object resulting in unexpected behavior.